# Oracle 11 - dropped constraint error

Tags: oracle11g

I had to drop from my schema a constraint named "ADUS_UK" (unique constraint).
It has been dropped, but it was still raising an error:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SURVEY.ADUS_UK) violated
```

I searched in sys constraint catalog, I tried a few things but nothing was fixing this. This makes me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was: when creating a constraint, oracle automatically create some indexes with the same name. I also dropped these indexes, and it works.